# IEE754 rounding modes: how is the error computed?

Tags: floating-point, precision

As an example, here's the output from a Java file I wrote. It has the binary representation of each number, aligned with what I manually computed the mantissa to be (truncated/rounded down).

```
    67108867: 67108864.000000
      100000000000000000000000011
       00000000000000000000000
    67108868: 67108864.000000
      100000000000000000000000100
       00000000000000000000000
    67108869: 67108872.000000
      100000000000000000000000101
       00000000000000000000000
```

Looking at 67108868, it's clear that Java is using either *round half towards zero,* or *round half towards even.* But how is the error used for rounding calculated? If a number is too big to properly fit in a mantissa, it seems like finding the exact error would be impossible. Maybe it uses the extra bits to the right, but for many fractions, wouldn't there be an infinite number of bits to consider?

I want to know the specific details of how rounding might be implemented in hardware or code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know what the rounded result is, it is not necessary to know all the bits of the exact result (of which there may be infinitely many). One only needs to know the bits up to what fits in the significand, the next bit, and whether or not the remaining bits are all zero. This produces four cases (for round-to-nearest-ties-to-even):

- Next bit after what fits is zero and all remaining bits are zero: The answer is exact; there is no error.
- Next bit is zero but it is not true that all remaining bits are zero: Round down.
- Next bit is one and all remaining bits are zero: The error is exactly ½ ULP, so round to even.
- Next bit is one but it is not true that all remaining bits are zero: Round up.

For simple arithmetic operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, this information is easily available by computing a fixed number of additional bits or by examing other data produced during the operation (such as the residue calculated while performing long division).

For complicated functions like trigonometric functions, we do not have complete proofs characterizing the work required to produce the necessary information. Most math libraries implement versions of these functions that are not guaranteed to be correctly rounded. If correct rounding is desired, an implementation can use arbitrary-precision arithmetic to continue refining the answer until it determines whether the result is above or below the rounding point (½ ULP).

Comment: Interesting. So for trig stuff, is it not sufficient to compute those few extra bits, or do we simply not know how to prove how many bits would be sufficient?

Comment: @warmCabin: A few extra bits are often sufficient but not always, and we do not generally know how many are needed. Generally, an algorithm for computing a function more and more precisely does not return bit-by-bit results. It gives you some number y and perhaps some sort of error bound or indication. Say you know the answer is in (y-e, y+e). If each number in (y-e, y+e) rounds to the same z, you return z. Otherwise, you refine the result to some new y1 and tighter error e1, so the answer is in (y1-e1, y1+e1). But the boundary where rounding changes might still be inside that interval.…

Comment: Generally, we cannot say, in advance, how many iterations of an algorithm are required before the interval is small enough that it does not straddle a rounding boundary. CRlibm was a project that involved solving this issue for certain functions and certain floating-point formats, and it produced useful progress but was not completed. For well-behaved functions, we always can refine an estimate to the point where we know what the correctly rounded result is, but we do not always know how long that refinement will take.